# Play sound in left or right speaker using android AudioTrack

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am playing sound with the help of AudioTrack in my APP but i want to play sound in specific speaker/ear means left speaker or right speaker or both speaker.

Following code i am using to play sound.

```
private AudioTrack generateTone(double freqHz, int durationMs)
{
    int count = (int)(44100.0 * 2.0 * (durationMs / 1000.0)) & ~1;
    short[] samples = new short[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i += 2){
        short sample = (short)(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (44100.0 / freqHz)) * 0x7FFF);
        samples[i + 0] = sample;
        samples[i + 1] = sample;
    }
    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        count * (Short.SIZE / 8), AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

    track.write(samples, 0, count);
    return track;
}
```

With following code i am calling this function to play sound.

```
AudioTrack soundAtSpecificFrequency =   generateTone(500, 6000);
soundAtSpecificFrequency.play();
```

Following code to stop playing sound.

```
soundAtSpecificFrequency.pause();
```

Can you please tell me what can the possible solution in this case or any other alternative solution?

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: And what is your question? You don't know how to play sound only in left or right speaker? Or what?

Comment: Yes how to play sound only in left or right speaker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AudioTrack` uses raw PCM samples to play sounds. The PCM samples are played in the following order (the first sample is played by the left speaker and the second sample is played by the right speaker):

LRLRLRLRLR

So you have to modify your samples array that you pass to `AudioTrack`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461243/how-to-play-two-sine-wave-on-left-and-right-channel-separately-with-16-bit-forma) could help too.

In your case just do the following:

```
// only play sound on left
for(int i = 0; i < count; i += 2){
    short sample = (short)(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (44100.0 / freqHz)) * 0x7FFF);
    samples[i + 0] = sample;
    samples[i + 1] = 0;
}
// only play sound on right
for(int i = 0; i < count; i += 2){
    short sample = (short)(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (44100.0 / freqHz)) * 0x7FFF);
    samples[i + 0] = 0;
    samples[i + 1] = sample;
}
```

Comment: Can you please bit more elaborate it. I am new in android development and i have also tried your specified solution but still i am facing problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and thanks a lot for your precious time. It works in my case.