# How to play two different frequencies in each ears? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, frequency, flutter-dependencies

I am currently using [sound_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_generator) `flutter plugin` to play frequencies. It has a static function `.setBalance` by which we can tell plugin to play that frequency in either left or right ear.

But I can only set balance for one frequency at a time. I want to play `132hz at left ear` and `135hz at right ear`.

Is there any way to do such?

Answer (score 1):

The audio libraries available today on pub.dev are high-level for **common use-cases.**

**To my knowledge, there is not an API that is low-level enough to have this kind of control in Flutter/Dart yet.**

[You may need to use native Android code to accomplish this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703976/play-2-different-audio-streams-on-left-and-right-speaker)