# AudioTrack setStereoVolume deprecated

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I did not manage to find solution what to use instead of deprecated AudioTrack's method setStereoVolume.

There is info about this in reference, but I am not sure how to use setVolume for muting left/right channel.

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. Applications should use
>   setVolume(float) instead, as it more gracefully scales down to mono,
>   and up to multi-channel content beyond stereo.

I need to play only one channel at a time, but I cannot find appropriate solution. 
I've already checked solution with LRLRLR samples, and playing one channel by setting every 2nd sample to 0, but did not help.

Thank you.

Comment: You should check whether you are setting the output configuration to 2 channel mode (`CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO`). If the output uses two separate channels then resetting samples in one of them *should* result in muting it.

Comment: Also, check that the output device does actually have 2 channels. Have you tried using headphones for example?

Comment: Yes, I use CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO. But how to reset samples in one channel? 
I have tried and currently, have desired behavior by using setStereoVolume, but it is deprecated, so I want to avoid usage of that method.

Comment: I ve tried this, but I dont hear nothing http://stackoverflow.com/a/27056765/1374065

Comment: I would suggest revealing relevant fragments of your code. The solution you are referencing suggests correct approach, but that's in case if you use uncompressed PCM data. If you are playing a compressed file, e.g. MP3 then it will not work.

Comment: I use PCM to play sounds at different frequencies. One tone, it is not MP3 or some other compressed format.